# Integrate Winston into node application

Tags: node.js, express, winston, express-winston

I have my node application architecture like this-

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
var app = express();
app.use('/route', Router);
```

**Router.js**

```
import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/route', Router.routerController);
```

**controller.js**

```
exports.routerController = async function (req, res) {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    // Actual API call
  } catch (error) {

  }
};
```

What will be the best way to integrate Winston for logging into such architecture. Is there a way in which I can integrate Winston in the entire application without placing log calls in every controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use middleware for that. see sth like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston

Comment: Is it possible to log stack trace in case of an error with express-winston?